# Webservice - how to deploy?

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, web-services

I am trying to write a simple webservice which produces a JSON string. What I really want to do is get some info from my database through this JSON string and use it in my Android application. I want to write it all in Java and try to avoid using php.

I am not sure how to deploy this thing to my remote server through Filezilla.

This is just not the end result at all. I just tried to write something that could produce a JSON string. I am using the jersey lib btw.

```
package services;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/webservice")
public class RestFulWebservice {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response produceJSON() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        double weight = 62;
        double height = 170;
        jsonObject.put("Weight", weight);
        jsonObject.put("Height", height);

        String result = "Produces JSON: \n" + jsonObject;
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }

}
```

I would really appreciate any advice. If I can just produce a dynamic JSON string I think I know how to read in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs to run in a webcontainer of some sort (tomcat, jetty etc).

You have a couple of options, either a separately installed webcontainer or one embeddded in your application.

You then need to build your compiled code into a war (to deploy to a separately installed container) or an executable jar (for an embedded container).

If you're just getting started with web containers then its probably best to read up on something like tomcat.

Alternatively you can look at something like [spring boot.](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/06/spring-boot-simplifying-spring-for-everyone)

Comment: so I need some sort of servlet?

Comment: There are a few ways of deploying jersey.  The user guide has a [section devoted to deployment](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html)

Comment: Can I use Eclipse to do this? Like creating a Dynamic Web Project?

Comment: You certainly can.  The deployment method you choose will dictate that.  If you go for a servlet approach, then you will need an eclipse web project.  Alternatively, an embedded deployment approach can be run as a java application which starts the embedded web container.  Have a read of section 4.5 of the link I posted in the earlier comment

Comment: Which of the ways do you recommend for my purpose? :)

Comment: That's a difficult one to answer.  These days for a smallish hobby  project I would tend to head for an embedded web container.  If it is a production system with a large number of users I would be more inclined towards a separate web container and war file.  But that's just my opinion.

Comment: I will try to implement the separate web container. :) Let's see how it works out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Execuse me but I don't understand JSON object is received by java code or the JSON objecy is sent from java code

Comment: I didn't understand your sentence, I am sorry.

Comment: I mean you want to send this json object (contains weight and height) from where to where ??

Answer (score 0):

Deploying Java applications on the server is not like in PHP where you just copy files.
You need to [build a WAR (web archive) package](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/packaging003.htm) and deploy it in a servlet container, for example [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org).